# Is there any issue with encrypting and encoding serialized data?

Tags: c#, serialization

Here is my code, I get this error when deserializing it.  I'm testing it in the same call, so versioning of .net shouldn't be an issue.  My user data is a basic poco object.

Step 1, Serialize and encrypt:

```
    byte[] userDataArray;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, _logicLibrary.userData);
        userDataArray = ms.ToArray();
    }

    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(userDataArray);

    var encrytedUserData = logic.Encrypt(data);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encrytedUserData);
```

Step 2 decrypt and deserialize:

> ```
>     public UserData DeserializeUserData(string data)
>     {
>         string decryptedSerializedData = _logicLibrary.RunDecrypt(data);
>
>         var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decryptedSerializedData);
>
>         BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
>         using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(dataBytes))
>         {
>             return bf.Deserialize(ms) as UserData;
>         }
>
>     }
> ```
>
> My error when deserializing is this:
>
> {"Binary stream '189' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible
>   causes are invalid stream or object version change between
>   serialization and deserialization."}

Comment: Why are you converting the bytes from the binary serialization to a string? This is likely the cause of your problems.

Comment: You're destroying your serialized data, it's binary data, you can't convert it to an string without corrupting it.

Comment: it is user data and needs to be encrypted and persisted.  thought this would work.

Comment: No, converting random bytes to a string using the UTF8 decoding will not work, it will lose some data in the process. If you need to have it as a string use [Convert.ToBase64String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`, and the corresponding `FromBase64String` on the other end.

Comment: No it wouldn't, you can't represent chars like 0 or 255 on an string, it will be cropped, if you must use strings for encription (but I can't think a good reason for it) at least convert your data to a base64 string which can be reverted to a binary array without corrupting it.

Comment: Though I must say that an encryption routine that only works with strings looks fishy.

Comment: Simply: encryption encrypts bytes and decrypts bytes. Unless there is a coding mistake you get back *exactly* what you encrypt. Encryption does not know or care what it encrypts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the good suggestions here I reworked my encryption methods to accept input and outputs of type byte[].  After that I made sure that any data that was not a string never touched a Encoding.UTF8 based on lots of stuff including the following [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/).  These tips combined to make my code work.  UserData is a custom class.

```
private UserData DeserializeUserData(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] decryptedSerializedData = logic.Decrypt(data);


    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(decryptedSerializedData))
    {
        return bf.Deserialize(ms) as UserData;
    }

}

private byte[] SerializeUserData(UserData userData)
{
    byte[] userDataArray;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, userData);
        userDataArray = ms.ToArray();
    }

    return logic.Encrypt(userDataArray);

}
```

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is not intended for persisted storage or cross machine use. It is extremely version change intolerant and it is possible to get data that is suddenly not readable after doing a windows update or releasing a new version of your program. You may want to consider a different 3rd party binary serializer like `ProtoBuf` or switch to a more change tolerant built in serializer like `XmlSeralizer`.

Comment: That is a good point.  In this case I believe we are okay as we are using this for state persistence.  The same machine/code which creates the binary data is the only one deserializing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like

```
Convert.ToBase64String(arrayOfData);
Convert.FromBase64String(stringBase64Encoded);
```

to get a string and convert it back to a byte array.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This gives me "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."  I'll keep playing.